# PDF's not opening on Safari iOS or OSX

Tags: pdf, safari

I have just recreated some PDF's on my mac, and uploaded them to parse.com.
Now if i try to select them from parse.com, or my own website (using iOS or OSx) the file is downloaded rather than opened. All the PDF's is created before today still work fine. I have created the files using MS Word and a booklet printer but this has always worked before. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the `Content-Disposition` headers.

Answer (score 0):

Just sorted it. It seems to be related to the Parse.com beta Dashboard. When I upload files to Parse.com using the new Dashboard, they will not open but will only download. When I deleted all the files and uploaded them again using the old Parse.com Dashboard everything worked ok.